# laravel folder changed routes not working

Tags: laravel

I have placed the whole laravel project inside a folder name myproject.
And my laravel was working perfectly as www.domain.com/myproject.

Now I copied the whole project and placed it inside a new folder mobile.
But in www.domain.com/mobile the root page is running perfectly but the next route is giving error 404.

Please assist

My folder structure,

```
apache_htdocs   
   -Mobile
      -project
        -app
        -bootstrap
        -config
        - ---
```

Basically i copied the public folder and placed a new folder project and copied everything except public in that folder.

Comment: Tried clearing the route cache `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: @linktoahref  yes i did , no solution

Comment: and done `composer dump-autoload` to autoload the files?

Comment: yes did already

Comment: please check your route with `php artisan route:list` or explain your folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear your routes so Laravel will create the routes with the new path, with this in the command line: `php artisan route:clear`.

If you see no changes try to list or your views with this `Route::getRoutes();` 
in your controller or this `php artisan routes` in command line, in order to check the path.

Comment: when i use Route::getRoutes();   it gives me error that the particular route is not defined